# In Virginia, can a crop dusting/seeding operation refuel and re-supply on agricultural property that they are working?

Tags: faa-regulations

It has been reported that a crop dusting/seeding operator is refueling and re-supplying his plane on agricultural property that he is working. Just trying to make sure this operator is operating within any regulations set forth for crop dusting/seeding operations.

Comment: As in, landing on a runway that's part of / owned by the same farm that he's applying (whatever) to? Is that the scenario you're asking about?

Comment: Ralph, yes, the pilot is landing on the property owned by the same farm that he is applying seeding.

Comment: Note that there may be additional state/county laws for such operations, which are not covered by FAA regulations. You may have to ask on [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/) regarding those laws.

Comment: If the runway would be legal to land on generally, there shouldn't be anything about applying seed to the same owner's other fields that makes it off-limits. All the rules that apply everywhere else (permission required, handling of chemicals, etc) would still apply, but I don't think that same-ownership would create any particular barrier to using that particular runway for resupplying to seed those particular fields.

Comment: What is the nature of the reports?  i.e. neighbors complaining about noise, or environmental or safety concerns around off-airport refueling operations?  Because that drives different answers.

Comment: I think it is a combination of noise of the operation, and the safety and environmental concerns associated with refueling and re-supplying in an agricultural field. I believe this  individual may live within sight of the farm and saw what was going on and then expressed his concern.

Comment: Well, ground based tractors also make noise, spray chemicals, and need to be refueled.  My first impression is that there's nothing abnormal or illegal about this as long as it is done on private property.  (Complainers will complain, and aviation seems to draw a disproportionate number of them...)

Answer (score 5):

It seems like you are broadly asking "is it legal to land in a random field" the broad answer is, *yes* generally you need the owners permission and so long as there is no local ordinance preventing it you can land, refuel, resupply and do what you need in a field. You can find more info in these question

- [What procedures are followed for a planned landing in a field?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/36416/what-procedures-are-followed-for-a-planned-landing-in-a-field)
- [When it comes to private airports those marked on sectionals with (Pvt) what frequency's do they use if any at all](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/93801/when-it-comes-to-private-airports-those-marked-on-sectionals-with-pvt-what-fre)
- [How are unpaved strips created and maintained?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/19443/how-are-unpaved-strips-created-and-maintained)
- [What are the FAA regulations on grass airstrips?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/23578/what-are-the-faa-regulations-on-grass-airstrips/23581#23581)

Comment: Broadly, maybe... I didn't interpret the question as being about landing though.  As Ralph mentioned in a comment above, I think there's more risk in violating some obscure fuel and chemical handling regulation, and that was really how the question was worded.

Comment: @MichaelHall I read the question as focusing on the fact that the same owner owns both the landing strip and the field being worked -- which I don't think adds any limitation to the operation. Regardless of the ownership, all the fuel/chemical handling regs (federal/state/local) apply, and rules about where you can/can't land apply. But those all apply no more & no less in the case of same-owner than they would if the landing was on somebody else's property. "On property that he is working" doesn't make things less permissive, but there's ***plenty*** of rules to be met, regardless.

Comment: @RalphJ, I read it that farmer owns the land too...  In summary:  Farmer pays crop duster to dust crops, plane lands in farmers field to refuel and replenish, is the the refueling and replenishing legal?  (vs "is landing in the field legal"...)  Either way, I think the complaintents would accept any answer in favor of shutting it down.

Comment: "Either way, I think the complaintents would accept any answer in favor of shutting it down."  Agree!